# Yii Framework: The table for active record class cannot be found in the database

Tags: postgresql, yii

I'm hoping the hivemind has some more suggestions on dealing with this error from Yii Framework. The exact error, specific to our setup is:

> **CDbException** The table "users" for active record class "Users"
>   cannot be found in the database.

I'm using Yii Framework 1.1.11-dev from SVN, though this was just an attempt to fix the problem. We were running the latest stable version 1.1.10.

We are trying to deploy to our live server with code that is working in my dev env. I feel like the problem is almost certainly a database configuration difference, but I'm not sure where to find it.

I have already searched here and searched the Yii forums where I found this problem listed a couple of times. Suggested fixes we've already tried include

- removing the host and port from the dsn
- with and without schema for the tablename (ie "users" and "public.users")
- GRANT ALL ON DATABASE [dbname] TO postgres
- Grant all on each table in the db using code found [here](http://bensbrain.blogspot.com/2004/08/postgres-grant-on-all-tables-in.html)

The environments are as follows:

- DEV  -  OSX 10.7, PHP 5.3.10, PostgreSQL 9.0.3
- PROD - FC15, PHP 5.3.10, PostgreSQL 9.0.7

The error indicates the table "users" does not exist, though it quite clearly does.

```
~$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.0.7)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dt
                    List of relations
 Schema |             Name             | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------------------------------+-------+----------
  { ... removed for brevity ... }
 public | users                        | table | postgres
```

Our configuration in protected/config/main.php

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'pgsql:dbname=lppsync',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => '',
),
```

And the relevant part of the Users model is

```
class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Users the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
```

Comment: Maybe some other config file is being merged with the main one overriding database settings? You could check the actual db configuration being used by `echo Yii::app()->db->connectionString; echo Yii::app()->db->tablePrefix; ...` somewhere in your controller. Also, isn't it an issue with table prefixes?

Comment: @galymzhan Thanks for the suggestion. `echo Yii::app()->db->connectionString;` shows just what is set in our configuration file and checking the tablePrefix setting returns null. We have no table prefixes set up so this should work.

Comment: Yii [caches](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#schemaCachingDuration-detail) db metadata, probably that is the issue? Try to clear your metadata cache or disable cache at all.

Comment: Thanks to clearing the metadata cache (hat tip @galymzhan) I found the real problem was in how we loaded the database.

Comment: New users can't answer their own questions for 8 hours so:

The data import was all wrong. Data was imported to the user's database instead of the correct dbname. In this case 'postgres'. It was all our mistake from the beginning. 

To be clear, the fix in this case is to re-import the data to the correct location, or change the Yii config (our decision). Blargh! I spent hours on this last night.

New connection settings:
`'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'pgsql:dbname=postgres', 'emulatePrepare' => true, 'username' => 'postgres','password' => '',)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the data was not imported to the named database. Instead it was imported to the user's database. In this case 'postgres'.  The fix in this case is to re-import the data to the correct location, or change the Yii config (our decision). New connection settings:

```
'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'pgsql:dbname=postgres', 'emulatePrepare' => true, 'username' => 'postgres','password' => '',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii [caches](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#schemaCachingDuration-detail) db metadata, probably that is the issue? Try to clear your metadata cache or disable cache at all.

The /`wwwroot/assets` folder usually contains those cache files.

Check also that you haven't run out of space on your device (disk).

Source: Quoting one of the comments to this Question - [Yii Framework: The table for active record class cannot be found in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757346/yii-framework-the-table-for-active-record-class-cannot-be-found-in-the-database#comment13982099_10757346)

Comment: I check /wwwroot/assets and there is no cache in there

Comment: did you check that you haven't run out of space on your device (disk)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I enabled xdebug and had my space run out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar error with MySQL. In my case the problem was that I had made a mistake in granting the rights for the user. Running MySQL client I got a proper "command denied message", but from Yii perspective it looked like the tables did not exist at all.

The solution was to grant the rights properly:

`grant all on yiiapp.* to 'yii'@'localhost' identified by 'yii';`