# Yii - The table for active record class cannot be found in the database

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have created a website using the Yii framework and I get the error " **The table for active record class cannot be found in the database.**". I have confirmed and the table does exist in the database. I have also verified that the table name in the database has the same case as the table name in the model class.

Moreover this error is appearing randomly. Has any one else faced this problem? Thanks for your time.

**Update**
Model Code:

```
class User extends CWIActiveRecord
{

        public $confirmEmail;
        public $confirmPassword;
        public $currentPassword;
        public $newPassword;
        public $newPasswordRepeat;
        private $_identity; 

    public function tableName()
    {
        return "cwi_user";
    }

   public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
   {
        return parent::model($className);
   } 

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'isSubscribed' => 'Receive updates about investment, special offers and updates on '. Yii::app()->name,
        'verificationToken' => 'Verification Token',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'accountType' => 'Account Type',
        'createdBy' => 'Created By',
        'lastModifiedBy' => 'Last Modified By',
        'createdDate' => 'Created Date',
        'lastModifiedDate' => 'Last Modified Date',
        'createdIp' => 'Created Ip',
        'lastModifiedIp' => 'Last Modified Ip',
        'currentPassword' => 'Existing Password',
        'newPassword' => 'New Password',
        'newPasswordRepeat' => 'Confirm Password',
    );
}

}
```

Database Config:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Comment: Paste the code and your table name. And have you connected to the db correctly in config..?

Comment: I have pasted the model code. As I have mentioned in the question, the error only appears randomly. It works most of the time. If you need any other information then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the error is about THIS model. Perhaps the random fact is about another model that you use once in a while. Seems very weird unless you have a wonky database connection.

Comment: Check your db connection in the config that might be the problem..
yoou could also look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757346/yii-framework-the-table-for-active-record-class-cannot-be-found-in-the-database?rq=1

Comment: 2 posible cases: A). your db config is bad or B). you have 2 User models

Answer (score 0):

I have then same problem .mysql's temp dir may be full,and some query need to write large amounts of data into temp space ,and then error thrown.check by "df -h" and  clear /tmp, may take effect